# DataGridView C# Default Values in Rows During Edit Mode

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, dataset, default-value

I have a program that I use to enter values into a database using a gridview.  The gridview is populated with an 'empty' result from a DataSet that queries that database from the table I want.  This fills the grid with the proper columns that I want (ie. a grid with an empty row from a certain table in a db). When you fill in the columns, I take the data and manually update the db.

Basic example of how I use the gridview:

```
this.fullUutDataTableAdapter.Fill(this.dalsaUutDataSet.ResultsFullUut);  
DataView dv = this.dalsaUutDataSet.ResultsFullUut.DefaultView;
Grid_modify.DataSource = dv;            
foreach(DataGridViewRow dr in Grid_modify.Rows)
{
    dr.Cells["YieldID"].Value = -1;
}
```

However, I want to have certain columns to have Default Values.  I have tried changing the column's default value, but you cannot change the property, only 'GET' it.  Alternatively, I tried parsing through the rows in the empty grid and filling in the values.  This works fine when the grid loads up initially (values show up in proper places).  HOWEVER, when as soon as I enter edit mode these values clear to nothing.

NEXT, I tried using some of the RowEdit Events and tried filling in values when edit mode is entered, however, this causes problems when you enter and leave edit mode.  Seems to be a more complicated and messy way of doing things that seemingly necessary.

So the question really is, what is the best way to fill a gridview with default values in certain columns?

I would prefer the "cleanest" solution possible.  However, I recognize that things don't always work out that way.....

Thanks for your help in advance!  Cheers.

Comment: You can change this the question is ..what does the existing code look like that you are currently using.. perhaps that's where the issue lies...

Comment: I added a few lines of code, but much more than this will only make things more confusing.  I'm hoping for a solution that generally answers this problem, not just specific to my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this: [How To Specify Default Values for DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b22t666e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: This will do the trick.  Not too hard to make it work for many different data column either.  Thanks!