# Default Uneditable Values in Datagridview When the User Edits a New Row to Add to a Database

Tags: c#, datagridview

I wanted to used a datagridview to let a user edit certain columns in a MYSQL DB. I'm starting of with an empty table. So if:

```
...
connection.Open();
mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM `expenses` ", connection);
connection.Close();
DataSet DS = new DataSet();
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
...
```

gives me a datagridview with all the correct col names at the top and one empty row with >* at the very left of this empty row and if I begin to edit a cell in this row the very left now turns into a pencil icon and a 2nd new "proto" row appears below with just a * at the very left. This is OK, I think it's standard behavior.

My questions is how to always show and enforce a default value in a few of the columns of these "empty" and "proto" (don't really know the correct term to describe these rows). I don't know how these rows/cells are accessed programmatically. The bottom line is that I'd the user to have/see uneditable values in certain cells as they edit a new row.

Then user edits the cols which I make editable. And, new rows as a result get added to the dataview. Actually adding the rows to the DB table is next but I wanted to know if this can be done first.

Comment: Already asked and answered:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978771/datagridview-c-sharp-default-values-in-rows-during-edit-mode     Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

use `DefaultValuesNeeded` event

```
private void dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender,
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells["Region"].Value = "WA";
    e.Row.Cells["City"].Value = "Redmond";
    e.Row.Cells["PostalCode"].Value = "98052-6399";
    e.Row.Cells["Country"].Value = "USA";
    e.Row.Cells["CustomerID"].Value = NewCustomerId();
}
```

for more information read 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b22t666e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx